# Symbol's value as variable is void

Tags: defun

first, defined this interactive function:

```
(defun system-is-windows ()
  (interactive)
  (string-equal system-type "windows-nt"))
```

then call this function in one setting.el file

```
; don't show the scroll bar
(if system-is-windows (scroll-bar-mode 0))
```

and it throws back the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable system-is-windows)
  (if system-is-windows (scroll-bar-mode 0))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-51294> nil "c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/settings/general-settings.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1439
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/settings/general-settings.el" "c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/settings/general-settings.el" nil t)
  require(general-settings)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 849
  load-with-code-conversion("c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/init.el" "c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("c:/Users/user/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1000be22d>)()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: Reviewers, answerers: As there are *lot* of Q's and A's on this site now, it's more and more important/helpful to check for duplicate Q's. There are many Q's with "void-variable", and the reasons for the error are multiple, so multiple such Q's are appropriate. But this one - using a function without parens or `funcall` or `mapcar` etc. is a duplicate (and even perhaps more than one dup?).

Comment: We really could use some help creating Community Q & A that removes some of the extraneous stuff from existing Q's to get to the hearts of the issues.

Answer (score 2):

The following code:

```
(if system-is-windows (scroll-bar-mode 0))
```

Does not evaluate `system-is-windows` as a function, but tries to
evaluate it as a variable.  That's why you're getting the
`(void-variable system-is-windows)` error message.

Instead, you need to write:

```
(if (system-is-windows)
    (scroll-bar-mode 0))
```

The parentheses tell Emacs that you are evaluating it as a function.

Comment: Thank you @Dan.  adding `()` around function name fixes the issue.